# How to handle One-Time User interaction

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I am working on a solution that consists of a *Domain Model* (in its separate project) and a *MVC3 Web Application* (again in its own project).

In my MVC3 application, I am listing posts (accessed via a Repository on the Domain), and each post has a ***like button***, and of course in the Domain Model, the Post entity has a property of:

```
public int Likes { get; set; }
```

What I want to allow is for a visitor of my site (i.e. a guest) to be able to hit the Like button on a post, but only once. So that he/she is able to like a post **once**.

What is the best way of achieving this ? Cookies ? Saving IP Addresses in Database along with the Post Id liked ? Or some other way ?

I'm really confused, cause whichever way I think of, there are always holes in the logic, where a user can Like a post twice !

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: That's the whole point of being anonymous on the interwebs. The user can hit your app from a different IP, and they can definitely clear their cookies. If you really want to be sure no one likes something twice, they'll need to authenticate.

Comment: Cool thanks David. Of the Two, Cookies vs IP saving .. which one would YOU do if you were in my situation ?

Comment: Only choosing one, I'd encrypt a value (like a GUID or something) on the server side, and store that in the cookie. That way, I could track the users that don't regularly clear cookies *and* the client couldn't modify the value. They could only delete it.

Comment: Thanks David. What would that encrypted value (GUID) represent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a loot at this Q&A: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/94095/how-to-prevent-same-user-rating-a-web-content-like-video-more-than-once

**Bottom line:** There is no way to absolutely prevent multi-votes, but you can partially mitigate the risk given enough development efforts.

Comment: **Thank You Ofer**. That was an interesting read. I think I'll go with David's suggestion after I get my head clear on his words :)

Answer (score 0):

An encrypted cookie could just represent a unique user in a manner they couldn't modify (however, they could delete)

```
public ActionResult Like()
{
    var cookie = Request.Cookies["SecureCookieName"].Value;
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie))
    {
        string plainTextGuid = Decrypt(cookie);
        if(_db.Likes.Any(l => l.UniqueID == plainTextGuid))
            return null;
    }

    // if you're here, this is a "new" user
    Guid guid = new Guid();

    // TODO: persist Like to database including unencrypted guid.ToString()

    // set cookie value to encrypted
    Request.Cookies["SecureCookieName"].Value = Encrypt(guid.ToString());

    // or whatever logic you need
    return null; 
}
```

The `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` methods can include encryption of your choice.